# Writing Django Test for Django Haystack which uses Solr as backend

Tags: django, solr, django-haystack, pysolr

I am using Django 1.4, Django-Haystack 2.0 and Solr (pysolr 2.0.15). I have to write test cases in Django for Haystack. I have written indexes for the models and defined some functions like `index_queryset`. So, now I am in a fix on how to write test cases for the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well - if you are not using some special pysolr features (like proximity search) I suggest to use Simple backend in testing. You probably do not want to test how Haystack with pysolr works, because it is already tested and it is search, which is hard to predict all results and just will take long if you want to remove and build indexes often in tests.

You probably just want to test what you have written, e.g. those `index_queryset` function or maybe some `prepare_*` functions you added - test them completely separately (what is given and what they returns), just as unit tests should do - without any pysolr related stuff.

Comment: How would one tell, for example, Travis to use a different backend when running tests?